# Error during checkout with VISA card

Tags: javascript, html, css, nopcommerce

I'm completely new nopCommerce. One of my client is getting error during check out with VISA card. He is getting the following screen. I'm not sure where do I start to troubleshoot. Can you please help me? Some how I'm not able to post exact HTML document. But please consider below code as properly formatted HTML.

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">

    (function (f, b) {
        if (!b.__SV) {
            var a, e, i, g;
            window.mixpanel = b;
            b._i = [];
            b.init = function (a, e, d) {
                function f(b, h) {
                    var a = h.split(".");
                    2 == a.length && (b = b[a[0]], h = a[1]);
                    b[h] = function () {
                        b.push([h].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)))
                    }
                }
                var c = b;
                "undefined" !== typeof d ? c = b[d] = [] : d = "mixpanel";
                c.people = c.people || [];
                c.toString = function (b) {
                    var a = "mixpanel";
                    "mixpanel" !== d && (a += "." + d);
                    b || (a += " (stub)");
                    return a
                };
                c.people.toString = function () {
                    return c.toString(1) + ".people (stub)"
                };
                i = "disable track track_pageview track_links track_forms register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config people.set people.set_once people.increment people.append people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user".split(" ");
                for (g = 0; g < i.length; g++) f(c, i[g]);
                b._i.push([a, e, d])
            };
            b.__SV = 1.2;
            a = f.createElement("script");
            a.type = "text/javascript";
            a.async = !0;
            a.src = "//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2.2.min.js";
            e = f.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            e.parentNode.insertBefore(a, e)
        }
    })(document, window.mixpanel || []);
    var mode = 'prd'.toLowerCase();
    var token = '';
    if (mode == 'demo') {
        token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    } else if (mode == 'prd' || mode == 'prda' || mode == 'prdk') {
        token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    } else if (mode == 'test') {
        token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    } else {
        token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    }
    if (token != '') {
        mixpanel.init(token, {
            persistence: 'localStorage'
        });
    }


</script><!-- end Mixpanel -->         



<script type="text/javascript">
    if (self !== top && typeof mixpanel !== "undefined") {
        mixpanel.track("inFrame", {
            "merchant_id": "XXXX(actual number here)",
            "tid": "XXXX(actual number here)"
        });
    }


</script>
```

```css
 <style type="text/css">
        BODY, TD, INPUT, SELECT, TEXTAREA, BUTTON, .normal {
            font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
            font-size: 10pt;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        .small {
            font-size: 10pt;
        }

        .medium {
            font-size: 14pt;
        }

        .large {
            font-size: 18pt;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<!-- process-transaction-response -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://www.myvirtualmerchant.com?
          ssl_approval_code=++++++&
          ssl_cvv2_response=&
          ssl_exp_date=XXXX(actual number here)&
          ssl_account_balance=0.00&
          ssl_get_token=&
          ssl_token=&
          ssl_departure_date=&
          ssl_token_response=&
          ssl_result_message=DECLINED&
          ssl_invoice_number=XXXX(actual number here)&
          ssl_description=Name1+Name2&
          ssl_amount=184.48&
          ssl_txn_id=GUID&
          ssl_result=1&
          ssl_card_number=XXXX(actual number here)&
          ssl_completion_date=&
          ssl_txn_time=10%2F28%2F2016+04%3A03%3A18+PM&
          ssl_avs_response=G">
    <style type="text/css">
        BODY, TD, INPUT, SELECT, TEXTAREA, BUTTON, .normal {
            font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
            font-size: 10pt;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        .small {
            font-size: 10pt;
        }

        .medium {
            font-size: 14pt;
        }

        .large {
            font-size: 18pt;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<form name="frmMenu" action="#" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="dispatchMethod" />
    <input type="hidden" name="permissionDesc" />
    <input type="hidden" name="menuAction" />
    <input type="hidden" name="thClientID" value="" />
</form> <!-- start Mixpanel -->

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add screen of an error, i cannot find any error in the question.

Comment: That's what I've so far.. But I can ask client to send screen shot.

Comment: Yeah, that's good, if you add a screen of it.

Comment: You shouldn't be posting your keys...

Comment: @Div As requested I've added image of error

Comment: @Mooseman is it ok now?

Comment: @gmailuser Yup. Just looking out for your client.

Comment: @Mooseman do you have any clue for the error?

Comment: @gmailuser I see a result_message declined to it's some error with your payment processor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128093/discussion-between-gmail-user-and-mooseman).